# Testing if object exists in joined ActiveRecord query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

I have User model that is related to a Friend model (has_many / belongs_to)

After joining, I would like to be able to check if a certain friend object exists in the friends that were joined to users:

```
users = User.joins(:friends).where("some condition")    # subset of total friends
fs = Friend.all
fs.each do |f|
  if users.friends.includes?(f) # match!
     ...
  else   # no match
     ...
end
```

The code as-is does not work and I am having difficulties getting this functionality in code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
users.friends.where(id: u.id).exists?
```

That should generate a query like so:

```
SELECT 1 AS one FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`friend_id` = 42 AND `users`.`id` = 1 LIMIT 1
```

You'll either get back the number 1 (considered "truthy"), or nil (considered "falsey").

*Side note:* Unless you need to use your `u` variable later, you can probably get away with simply placing `some_id` directly in the where clause, and not do the second `User` lookup.

**Edit**

Just noticed a problem in your loop that might be what is causing your original problem. When you loaded up the list of users, unless you have some `limit` clause or invoked `.first`, you'll get back an array of users. So I'm guessing your application is crapping out on this line:

```
users.friends.includes?(f)
```

Because `.friends` is a method of a `User` object, not of an array.

So you'll have to do a nested loop instead like so:

```
fs.each do |f|
    users.each do |u|
        u.friends.includes?(f)
    end
end
```

Note that this method might be very slow, depending on the number of friends and users. It is a very inefficient algorithm, which is why I'm trying to understand your situation better in the comments, because I'm certain there's a more efficient way to accomplish your task.

Comment: I did not want to query the db again. The point was to check the already 'joined' activerecord collection

Comment: @Jason With your query the way it is presently, you don't have a choice in the matter. Remember that active record relationships are lazy loaded. Meaning, your `users` or `u` objects don't yet have populated `friends` lists. Only when you attempt to use the association will they be loaded (resulting in another database call). If you examine your log, you will notice one query for the initial `User` lookup, and then when you try to do something with the `friends collection, you'll see another lookup. [part 1 or 2]

Comment: @Jason [part 2 of 2] I'm guessing you're concerned about the performance hit of touching the database again. I can post an alternative with eager loading, if you like, but then you're looking at having to iterate over an array in Ruby, rather than allow the database optimizations to take place. In short, assuming you have proper indexes on those columns, the DB lookup in this case will probably be a lot faster than a linear array search.

Comment: @Tegg, correct. the issue is that in my code I will be iterating over many friends and checking for a match each time. This will cause the N + 1 problem, so I assumed that a DB lookup each time would be more costly in terms of performance than searching the array in Ruby. What do you think?

Comment: @Tegg I unfortunately have no real-world feel for the performance of an app that iterates like this over thousands of rows. That is probably why I am so cautious. This would be for the back-end admin and would only be run once a day when email is being sent out.

Comment: @Jason Ohh ok, I understand now. I think you'd still have the same issue even with the array, because you're iterating through it N times linearly. In the situation you described, is the `u` User object the same? In other words, when you "iterate over many friends" and do your match checking, is it always checking against that same `u` object?

Comment: @Tegg, I changed the code in my question to make it clearer. I should have been more specific from the get-go, my apologies.

Comment: @Jason No not on this case. The `includes` method is an array method, so rails will first load all the friends for that user, and then iterate one by one until it finds one that meets your condition. There might be lots of other ways to solve this problem though, it all depends on the situation. For example, could you get away with something like this  instead: `User.join(:friends).where(friend_id: some_id)`. That will give you every user who is friends with this user.

Comment: Sorry I just noticed you updated your code. I'm on my phone, page doesn't auto update. Let me examine.

Comment: @Jason ok after looking at your updated code, I think what you're doing is ultimately unnecessary (unless I'm missing something). Your join will effectively already include all the "matching" friends. Ex: user1 has fr1 and fr2 as friends. Your friend table has fr1, fr2 and fr3. Your join will only bring up fr1 and fr2 for that user. You dont need to check if fr3 is included in user1's friend list because the DB (as a result of the Inner join) already excluded it. See what I mean?

Comment: @Tegg, you are right, but the friends loaded initially are actually going to be a subset of the total list. I will then check against this subset to see if a friend exists in it.

Comment: @Jason Ok I think I'm getting a bigger picture. I see your update; are you saying that certain friends will be filtered by that `where` clause? If so, don't worry, that won't happen. Remember that any active record queries you place are invoked on the `User`. It will have no effect on the number of friends pulled up when you do `user.friends`. You **can** filter friends by doing `user.friends.where(some condition` however, but not by doing `User.joins(:friends).where...`